# Angular Material: How do you specify spacing between two columns in a layout?

Tags: angular-material

Suppose I have two columns in a single row in an Angular Material layout:

```
<div layout="row" flex>
  <div layout="column" flex="50">
    Content 1...
  </div>
  <div layout="column" flex="50">
    Content 2...
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, suppose I want to set an arbitrary amount of space between the columns (a "gutter" of, say, 10px). I could create a third empty div, set a small "flex" value and modify the "flex" values from 50 to something smaller, but that seems like a hack and would create a percentage-based gutter width. It seems like there should be a cleaner way to get an exact gutter without creating empty divs. Do I have to put classes on my column divs and set CSS margin values (and deal with left vs right, etc.)? Anyone have any pointers to do this the Angular Material way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the "Angular Material" way of doing things.  But I feel your pain.

Currently, I'm migrating some Bootstrap code over to Angular Material and do need a way of doing this.

Here's what I've done.

Since Angular Material's `layout` directive affects only immediate children, I do believe that is an Angular Material way of operating.  So, on the `layout` div, I add a class, `gutter` and here is the SASS (just prettier CSS, with variables) that accompanies that class:

```css
.gutter {
    (greater-than) * {
        padding-right: $layout-gutter-width;
        ~ * {
            padding-left: $layout-gutter-width;
        }
        &:last-of-type {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*notice* - I'm not sure how to put `>` inside there, so substitute that for "(greater-than)"

**Explanation**
`$layout-gutter-width` is actually defined by `angular-material.scss` which ships with Angular Material (and I use SASS in my project) but you can set it as whatever you want, CSS or SASS, 10px, 16px, 50px, whatever.

For those not entirely familiar with what's happening in this SASS:

`> *` here means "Any immediate descendant of..."
`~ *` here means "Any immediate sibling of..."
`&:last-of-type` here means "The very last of these immediate descendants..."

So, for every immediate descendant of the element with class `gutter`, we add `padding-right`.  For every subsequent sibling element, we add `padding-left`, and for the very last element, we remove the `padding-right`.  The first element will not have `padding-left` and the last element will not have `padding-right`.

Ultimately this gets the padding we want.

```html
<div layout="row" class="gutter" layout-align="center center">
    <div flex="50">
        ...
    </div>
    <div flex="50">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 'Material way' for your sample to get space between, nowadays at least, would be something like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" flex fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div fxLayout="column" flex="50">
    Content 1...
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" flex="50">
    Content 2...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do quite a bit with 'layout-margin'
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options
Examples:

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <div flex>Parent layout and this element have margins.</div>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-padding>
  <div flex>Parent layout and this element have padding.</div>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-fill style="min-height: 224px;">
  <div flex>Parent layout is set to fill available space.</div>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-padding layout-margin layout-fill style="min-height: 224px;">
  <div flex>I am using all three at once.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use layout-align with spaces between option.